# Create dropdown in DataTables with event action

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table with one column like this:

```
{
                 "render": function(d,t,r){
                     var $select = $("<select></select>", {
                         "id": r[0]+"start",
                         "value": d
                     });
                     $.each(statuslist, function (Value, Text) {
                         var opt = '<option value=' + Text.Value + '>' + Text.Text + '</option>';
                         if (Text.Text === r[3]){
                             $(opt).prop("selected", true);
                         }
                         $select.append(opt);
                     });
                     $select.attr("id", "opt" + r[0]);
                     $("#opt" + r[0]).on('change', function(){
                         SetStatus(r[0]);
                     });
                     return $select.prop("outerHTML");
                 }
             },
```

The statuslist is a list of four text-value pairs.  The fourth column is the status text of the row and I am trying to make that one selected.  Also, I'm trying to capture the event when the value of the select changes.  This does not work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple problems

- You're attaching event handler to the wrong element (`idXXX` vs `XXXstart`).
- You're attaching event handler in the wrong place, `render` callback can be called multiple times.

I would recommend to move event handler out of your table initialization code.

For example:

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
   // ... skipped ...
   columns: [
      // ... skipped ...
      {            
         "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
            var $select = $('<select/>', { 'class': 'ctrl-status' });
            $.each(statuslist, function (Value, Text) {
               var $opt = $('<option/>', { 'value': Text.Value, 'text': Text.Text });
               if (Text.Text === full[3]){
                  $opt.attr("selected", "selected");
               }
               $select.append($opt);
            });
            return $select.prop("outerHTML");
         }
      }
   ]
});

// Handle change event for status selection control
$('#example').on('change', '.ctrl-status', function(){
    var data = $('#example').DataTable().row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
    SetStatus(data[0]);
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lf2cm29f/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks but I get an error 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'row' on the change function.

Comment: I am using DataTables verison 1.10.15 and it is erroring on the 'row' function.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Dean.DePue, added example demonstrating the solution.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com when you select Text 1 from the dropdown list and then filtering the table using the search functionality using the keyword Text 2, the row containing Text 1 selection still appears. Did you notice this? The search functionality works on rendered objects?